# Using MSSQL Symmetric Keys with Coldfusion

Tags: sql-server, encryption, coldfusion, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to us MSSQL encryption with Coldfusion.  I can run the test query below just fine in SSMS however once I place it in a  tag it fails.  Any Ideas?  Thanks

```
<cfquery name="test" datasource="ag_hits">

    DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @str = #newBrowser#;

    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY hits
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE hits_cert;

   INSERT INTO hits(pc, ip, browser, dates)
   VALUES ('#pcname#', '#newIP#', ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('hits'),@str), #dates#);

   CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY hits;
<cfquery>
```

Comment: Just saying it "fails" does not provide enough information. If you are getting an error, please include the full error message. If not, how do the actual results differ from what you expected. On an unrelated note, you should be using `cfqueryparam` to protect against sql injection. Especially with databases like SQL Server which allow the execution of multiple statements.

Comment: It's probably a missing semi colon.  Comment out everything but the first line and run it.  Uncomment the code command by command until you find the one causing the problem.